# MySQL get 2% of the record

Tags: mysql, limit

I am trying to get 2% of the random sample record.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT (SELECT CEIL(0.02 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)));
```

This one gives a syntax error due to line 3. Is there anything I am doing wrong?
Or is there a better way to get n % of records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER()` provides one option:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) rn,
              COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM Orders
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 1.0*rn / cnt <= 0.02;
```

On MySQL 5.7 and earlier, we can simulate row number:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rn
    FROM Orders, (SELECT @rn := 0) AS x
    ORDER BY RAND()
) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Orders) o
WHERE 1.0*rn / cnt <= 0.02;
```

Comment: I think the easier way is to use limit the number of 2% of the records.
`SELECT CEIL(0.02 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders))` when run independently it gives a number. I wonder why it cannot be combined with limit

Comment: @DanielLee I'm not sure whether a subquery can appear inside a `LIMIT` clause.  In any case, the version I used is what I would prefer on a production system anyway.

Comment: Yes I guess limit doesn't allow subquery in the end. Then can you explain 
`COUNT(*) OVER () cnt` this one? And I tried to run your code and I get an error around ` ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND())`

Comment: @DanielLee It sounds like you're using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess so. but I can't check the version. I'm currently practicing using www.w3schools.com SQL DB.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a version which might work on your MySQL.  Hopefully it is clear why we'd rather use MySQL 8+ and analytic functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the edited one worked for me. But can you explain
`COUNT(*) OVER ()`? I understand the partition but can't figure out why you are counting it over ()

Comment: @DanielLee What follows `OVER` is the window clause.  For `COUNT(*) OVER ()`, with empty `()`, it just means no window, which defaults to the entire table.  So doing `SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt FROM Orders` would return every row from your table _plus_ a new column `cnt` which contains the total number of records in `Orders`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It makes sense. So alternatively I can use another subquery
`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)', right? But yours looks much neat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235771/discussion-between-daniel-lee-and-tim-biegeleisen).